# oscilloscope turning off during pulsed power tests

Tags: power, oscilloscope, pulse

I'm recording voltage and current waveforms using an oscilloscope. The application is pulsed power.

A problem I am having is the oscilloscope is losing power / turning off when I trigger the system. The oscilloscope is connected to voltage and current probes via coaxial cables. Power is provided to the oscilloscope by a battery-powered-UPS (which is disconnected from mains power during tests).

The oscilloscope can lose power immediately after triggering the system, or a few seconds later. Sometimes it seems to work just fine and I can record the desired waveforms. When the oscilloscope does lose power, it happens both when I measure voltage and current together, and when I measure them individually. When the probes are disconnected and the coaxial cable is lying on the floor, it also picks up a signal.

I think the oscilloscope is being turned off because the signal along the coaxial cables is too strong. I don't want this happen, and am concerned I'm damaging the oscilloscope.

What are some things I can do / need to consider to stop this happening? Even generally, what would cause an oscilloscope to lose power like this, and how would that be rectified?

My background is not electrical engineering so I am a bit lost. Appropriate search terms for me to use would also be helpful, so I can try to do some more self-research.

[image]

Comment: What kind of system are you taking measurements of here?

Comment: Are you sure that the UPS isn't dropping out briefly during your tests? That could cause the scope to shut off.

Comment: The system is a pulsed power unit. Internal capacitors and closing switches, then the electrical breakdown we want happens between external electrodes.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when the oscilloscope loses power, the UPS is tripped (it starts beeping, loses power and needs to be reset). During the tests the UPS is running off battery, and is physically unplugged from mains power. So the only connection is has is to the oscilloscope.

Comment: Questions here need to include *full* detail - in your case, you're going to have to disclose the entire experimental setup, both schematically and in the physical implementation.

Comment: It sounds like you need an EMC Engineer to evaluate shielding requirements for both conducted and radiated issues that trip the UPS. High energy discharges span a very wide bandwidth and can render some coax cables ineffective for shielding effectiveness or perhaps dielectric breakdown  Distributed grounds may be necessary.  Semi-rigid coax is far better with 50 ohm terminations AC coupled.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added a diagram to the original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the critical detail is missing from your diagram.  You are going to need to share information that would actually let someone replicate your experiment, before the issue is going to be apparent.  If you aren't willing to do that, then you can't use this site as a resource.

Comment: Your liquid cooled resistors become equal capacitors if immersed in same surface area of fluid, thus your imaginary R divider schematic is in reality more complex in self capacitance and inductance wires. So most likely your design is damaging your devices.

Answer (score 0):

A high power pulse generator is effectively an [EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) device. You need to shield both the computer and UPS from the EMP, both electrostatically (e.g. screen Faraday shield) and magnetically (e.g steel or mu-metal enclosure). It would also be useful to shield the input cables, but since at least some part of them must extend outside the enclosure, they should connect only through feed-through ports with a solid common ground to the enclosure. You'll also need to calculate how much energy the cables pick up -- you may need to create some means to bypass common-mode pickup or to route the cables through metal conduit.